# Mootools getElements("input[type=radio]") returns Object not Array

Tags: javascript, mootools

Can anyone shed some light as to why `getElements("input[type=radio]")` or `getElements("input[name=radioname]")` would return an Object rather than an Array as specified in the docs?

In my case, not only is this returning as Objects, but the key value is the index as a string `("0", "1"...)`, with a last value of key "length" and value of int n.

Any ideas?

Comment: Create an applicable test-case on http://jsfiddle.net (and post equivalent code here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which documentation are you referring to?

According to this : http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Element:getElements, it does return an array.

And the way you describe the object, it does looks like an array to me.

Comment: What an idiot I am. The issue was utterly unrelated. After going back and tinkering, it turns out that they are typing as arrays as expected.

Thanks.

*hangs head in shame*